# Rake command aborted when I try to use it on someone else's code

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have recently copied Ruby on Rails code from one machine onto mine. I have successfully installed all the proper versions of Ruby and Rails that was on the other machine onto mine. When I try to use the command `rake about` in the app's directory it gives me this error:

```
C:\ror\dev\AWI>rake about
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2
C:/ror/dev/AWI/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `require_relative'
C:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I believe I have the right version of MySQL2 downloaded onto my machine but it seems like this is what's causing the problem. Any ideas on how to run the rake command on my computer using code taken from a different computer? Thanks

Comment: reinstall the mysql2

Comment: Did you run bundler?

Comment: Yes, I can run bundler and it says I'm using `mysql2 0.4.10 (x64-mingw32)`.

Comment: What if you run `bundle exec rake about`?

Comment: Gives me this error: `C:\ror\dev\AWI>bundle exec rake about
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2
C:/ror/dev/AWI/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `require_relative'
C:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`